# LaTeX on the go

Tags: tools

I resently started to like Google docs. The ability to write every I am, anytime I want. Especially mobile, with a tablet. Because the best Ideas don't care what you are doing, they just pop in your head.

I also started to use LaTeX. Is there anything in the LaTeX world, that provides the flexibility and freedom something like Google docs?

Comment: There are more, but personally I use and like [ShareLatex](http://www.sharelatex.com)